# To Add Name,Email and Number to Contact Database

Tags: android

I am using autocomplete textview to pick contacts which is in contact list, and I want to save the name,email ,number which is not in contact list which should be displayed like form and when i click some "Add" button it should save in the contacts. How to do this thing?

Could any one help me please!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are many questions about adding contacts. Not sure how this is different from those. You can extract all the information to create contacts/add fields by reading those:

[How to add new contacts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android)

[How to add custom data/field in contacts in android 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954650/how-to-add-custom-data-field-in-contacts-in-android-2-0)

[New contacts created using ContactsContract do not appear in Contacts app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336019/new-contacts-created-using-contactscontract-do-not-appear-in-contacts-app)

[Adding contacts using ContactsContract in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680610/adding-contacts-using-contactscontract-in-batch)

Answer (score 0):

Use this article:

http://wubbahed.com/2007/12/21/android-development-contacts/

OR this one:

http://www.lacherstorfer.at/haris_blog/2008/03/android-howto-create-a-new-con.html

Hope this helps!!